# Problemas com o popup menu e o Immersive Mode

Tags: android

Eu configurei o meu aplicativo para usar o Immersive Sticky Mode, mas eu também utilizo alguns elementos que estão acima do contexto da Activity e que, quando o usuário interage com eles, o aplicativo sai do Immersive Mode e a status bar volta a ser exibida. Esses elementos são um dialog box e um popup menu de uma toolbar. Consegui impedir que a status bar aparecesse quando o dialog fosse chamado através do seguinte código dentro do meu método showDialog:

`dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);`

Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer o mesmo com o popup menu. Esses são os métodos de criação e de seleção do menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int choosenId = item.getItemId();

    switch (choosenId){
        case R.id.btn1:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn1);

        break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn2);

        break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn3);

        break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn4);

        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

E esse é o xml da minha toolbar:

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundDarker"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <Button android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/button_back_orange" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar isso em sua `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (hasFocus) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

Comment: Eu já tenho isso adicionado a todas as minhas Activities e funciona perfeitamente para elas, mas a questão é que isso não funciona para o popup menu.